# ESRI REST Api - need to download batches of tiles

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, rest, arcgis-rest-api, cache

So I wanted to use the ESRI REST Api to fetch map tiles for an application. Right now I am calling for each tile as I need it via its X/Y and zoom level(which is generating a bunch of http calls), but I'm wondering if there is a way to call for a batch of tiles in a single call.

I've been looking through the API documentation but hadn't found a command to get more than a single tile, I was wondering if anyone with more experience might know how.

Comment: There is nothing in the API to download all tiles at once, but you could look into writing your own script, or even Applications like Mobile Atlas cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that ESRI just added this feature, but only for users of ArcGis server - the public server will have it turned off. The feature is called [ExportTiles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r30000025t000000) and it has been introduced in 10.2.1 for REST API:

It'll export things into ArcGis's .Tpk or bundled image formats.